# Difference in Z result of ST_Transform

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, proj

Query:

```
with geom as (
    select st_transform(
        st_geometryfromtext(
            'POINT Z(114.19515060316667 22.3979100265 81.8574198829997)',4326) ,2326)as a)
select st_x(a),st_y(a),st_z(a) from geom;
```

**First server**: (Z transformed    81.8574198829997->84.71958220563829)

Google Cloud SQL europe-west8

"POSTGIS=""3.1.4 3.1.4"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""140"" GEOS=""3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 4392"" PROJ=""Rel. 6.0.0, March 1st, 2019"" LIBXML=""2.9.10"" LIBJSON=""0.15"" LIBPROTOBUF=""1.4.0"""

Result:

838149.9363960824(st_x), 828737.9267898238(st_y), 84.71958220563829(st_z)

**Second server**: (Z not transformed    81.8574198829997->81.8574198829997)

Google Cloud SQL europe-west3

"POSTGIS=""3.0.3 r3.0.3"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""130"" GEOS=""3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 4392"" PROJ=""6.1.1"" LIBXML=""2.9.4"" LIBJSON=""0.15"" LIBPROTOBUF=""1.4.1"" (core procs from ""3.0.0 r0"" need upgrade)"

Result:

838149.9363960418(st_x), 828737.9267898289(st_y), 81.8574198829997(st_z)

The answer from the first server is correct for our job. What can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FROM GDAL 3.0.1: coordinate vertical transformation without geoid #1946

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1946#issuecomment-544915251

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).